# How can I change the TextView text color on the appwidget?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-appwidget, textcolor

As I mentioned in the title, I cannot change the color of the TextView.(Programmatically)

I've tried the following codes but it doesn't work:

```
views.setTextColor( R.id.txtPtw2Gunes, context.getResources().getColor( R.color.widgetOrange ) );

views.setTextColor( R.id.txtPtw2Aksam, Color.parseColor( "#e4e4e4" ) );
```

How can I help you do this?

**EDIT:** `views.setTextColor( R.id.txtPtw2Gunes, context.getResources().getColor( R.color.widgetOrange ) );`

Actually the code I added works, but it doesn't work on the emulator. I found it working when I tested it on a real phone.

The subject may be locked.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try something like:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPtw2Gunes)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.widgetOrange));
```

or

```
((TextView)views.findViewById(R.id.txtPtw2Gunes)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.widgetOrange));
```

Comment: Actually the code I added works, but it doesn't work on the emulator. I found it working when I tested it on a real phone.

views.setTextColor( R.id.txtPtw2Gunes, context.getResources().getColor( R.color.widgetOrange ) );

Thanks for the answer.